# Equation containing $y^y$ simplifies to a linear equation in a convex optimization problem

Tags: optimization, exponential-function, convex-optimization

I have been solving a microeconomics problem related to optimization and ended up with the following equation:

$$\left(100\alpha\right)^{\alpha}\left(25\beta\right)^{\beta}-\left(65\alpha+5\beta\right)^{\alpha}\left(\frac{130}{3}\beta\right)^{\beta}>0$$

Being unable to express $\beta$ in terms of $\alpha$ or vice versa, I plugged it into desmos and got [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdRVE.png), which is somehow linear. My question is: **how is it possible for this monstrosity to somehow simplify to a linear function?** Furthermore, how do I simplify this equation to a linear one, or is it only possible computationally?

---

Some context: the microeconomics problem was to find the optimum of two Cobb-Douglas utility functions and corresponding budget limitations for some arbitary $\alpha, \beta$ within the restrictions below:

$$U_1(x,y) = x^{\alpha} y^{\beta},\quad\alpha, \beta \in (0;1), \quad 100x+400y-10000\leqslant0$$

and

$$U_2(x,y)=(x+5)^{\alpha} y^{\beta},\quad\alpha, \beta \in (0;1),\quad 100x+150y-6000\leqslant0$$

The linearity of the graph means that there is a directly proportional correlation between the preference for either utility function and exponent value, and I really want to figure out why this is the case, but I am unable to find any information about it online.

Comment: (65α+5β)^α is the main reason why I'm unable to express one variable in terms of the other, because I can't expand this part for a non-integer exponent -- I tried to plug in α=1 to get a precise value, but I am unable to proceed because of the y^y-like expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you let $\alpha = \gamma\beta$ then the equation becomes
$$
\begin{aligned}
0 &<
(100\gamma\beta)^{\gamma\beta}(25\beta)^\beta - (65\gamma\beta + 5\beta)^{\gamma\beta}\left(\frac{130}{3}\beta\right)^\beta \\
&= \left((100\gamma\beta)^\gamma\cdot25\beta\right)^\beta - \left((65\gamma+5)^\gamma \beta^\gamma\cdot\frac{130}{3}\beta\right)^\beta \\
&=\left(25(100\gamma)^\gamma\beta^{\gamma+1}\right)^\beta - \left(\frac{130}{3}(65\gamma+5)^\gamma\beta^{\gamma+1}\right)^\beta.
\end{aligned}
$$

This inequality is true iff the ratio of the first term to the second term is $>1$, which gives us
$$
\begin{aligned}
1&< \frac{\left(25(100\gamma)^\gamma\beta^{\gamma+1}\right)^\beta}{\left(\frac{130}{3}(65\gamma+5)^\gamma\beta^{\gamma+1}\right)^\beta} \\
&= \frac{\left(25(100\gamma)^\gamma\right)^\beta}{\left(\frac{130}{3}(65\gamma+5)^\gamma\right)^\beta} \\
\implies 1&< \frac{\left(25(100\gamma)^\gamma\right)}{\left(\frac{130}{3}(65\gamma+5)^\gamma\right)}.
\end{aligned}
$$
This results in a transcendental equation for $\gamma$, but if a solution exists, it implies that the original inequality is satisfied with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in a linear relation $\alpha = \gamma\beta$.

Comment: ohhhhh now it's so much more clear! thank you! we actually did something similar on calculus so I could've probably used it